# Siberian CMS String could not be parsed as XML error

Tags: php, siberiancms

During the installation I get the following fatal error:

> String could not be parsed as XML

Here are the full error details:

```
<pre><code>
Error log: error__5bb776ef8beb2.log

Stack Trace:

Fatal Error: 
ArrayObject Object
(
  [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
    (
        [exception] => Exception Object
            (
                [message:protected] => String could not be parsed as XML
                [string:Exception:private] => 
                [code:protected] => 0
                [file:protected] => D:\Ampps\www\AppEasy\lib\Siberian\Layout.php
                [line:protected] => 541
                [trace:Exception:private] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [file] => D:\Ampps\www\AppEasy\lib\Siberian\Layout.php
                                [line] => 541
                                [function] => __construct
                                [class] => SimpleXMLElement
                                [type] => ->
                                [args] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [file] => D:\Ampps\www\AppEasy\lib\Siberian\Layout.php
                                [line] => 71
                                [function] => _createXml
                                [class] => Siberian_Layout
                                [type] => ->
                                [args] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 1
                                    )
</code></pre>
```

How can I solve this?
I am using WSL for Windows for running with ubuntu 16.04 with php 7.2 running  a local PHP server on `localhost:8000`.

Comment: What string are you  trying to parse as XML?

Comment: actually the xml is correct but taking the wrong relative path. I can change the code but then the other parts of application stop working. So  I want help from someone who has worked on siberian cms